# Codeigniter and multiple postgre schema

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

im using the development version of Codeigniter 3.0.

I can see that there is a Schema property to the $db config. But it doesnt look like its using it for anything atm. as my script wont connect to multiple schemas.

Does anyone know how to setup CI with multiple Schemas in postgre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution by the CI Developers.
https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/commit/485a348a7a633d38f69a963e9f77e23077f75d11

I recommend you to download only the folder 'database' from this link of your CI system/core and add to your application/config/database.php the line...

```
$db['default']['schema'] = 'NAME_OF_YOUR_SCHEMA';
```

or if you are using with a array list, something like this:

```
$db['default'] = array('schema'=>'NAME_OF_YOUR_SCHEMA');
```

Comment: I tried this before posting, without any success. It might have been updated since then. So i will test it with my next project.

Comment: any idea how to do it in CI version 2?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this was driving me crazy, specially with migrations.

What works for me was:

```
$this->db->query('SET search_path TO <schema>');
```

For example, at the begining and end of the up() method:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->db->query('SET search_path TO <custom_schema>');
    ...
    # Database stuff here
    ...
    $this->db->query('SET search_path TO public'); //where migrations table exists
}
```

Try this to avoid pg_query() errors with schema.table (syntax) and relation "migrations" does not exist.